# Oracle dump, load to same table with new schema

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to perform an oracle dump of my data and then load it back in after re-installing the software.

The problem is however that as I re-install the software, the schema of the data which I just exported may have changed slightly.

In mysql, I would hand-edit the SQL formatted dump file before importing it to match any schema changes.

But Oracle uses a proprietary dump/load format :(

Any tricks to preserving my data? Thanks!
BH

Comment: What kind of changes? Table structures, column sizes, indexes, tablespaces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the data and import the data into another schema (created by you) and copy the data from your schema to newly created application schema with some sql statements.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I see that to copy the data between schemas, I can use this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869390/copying-data-between-oracle-schemas-using-sql